# "Not allowed to load local resource" error when knitting to HTML document and running on a server

Tags: javascript, html, json, r-markdown, prepros

I'm trying to load a local JSON file in an RMarkdown (knitting to HMTL):

````
```{js}

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("C:/Users/Data/my_json.json", function(data){
            console.log(data); 
        }).fail(function(){
            console.log("An error has occurred.");
        });
    });

```
````

So, I'm aware that I can't serve local files on chrome without running a server.  So, I dropped the HMTL output from the RMarkdown into Prepros, which comes with a built-in HTTP & HTTPS server.  It's running at `http://localhost:8848/` And still I get the errors:

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

and

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I fix this?  I assumed I could run local JSON files via Prepros, since it's spinning up a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser wont let you load a file from the host - that would be a huge security issue.

You need to make it so that the server has an endpoint that returns the JSON, and then put in the url for your getJSON call, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8848/path/to/my_json.json", function(data){
        console.log(data); 
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log("An error has occurred.");
    });
});
```

Comment: Dude!  That worked.  Thanks so much!  If it's not too much trouble, can you explain what's going on conceptually here?  I don't really understanding what's happening with the localhost and pointing to an "endpoint".  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Conceptually it's just basic browser security - the browser won't let a website just load a random file from the host.  If it did, any website you visit could do, e.g. ` $.getJSON("%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\cookies")`, which would load your cookies for all websites from the filesystem, then they could use your cookies to e.g. login to your bank.  By running a server, you are now running software which you control what it does - if you say "load this file", it lets you.  So you give access to the browser by having a "web page" which gives you the data